# Headphones recognised but produce no sound on antergos

Tags: arch-linux, audio, antergos, hp

Recently I installed Antergos-19.1 on my HP Omen laptop. Speakers work, but when I plug in headphones to audio jack, there no sound is produced at all. The output of the command `pactl list sinks |& grep -E "Sink|Ports|analog-ou"` is :

```
Sink #0
Ports:
    analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority: 10000, not available)
    analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority: 9000, available)
Active Port: analog-output-headphones
```

Therefore, headphones are detected and is set to be active port. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure your headphones are plugged in
2. Run:

```
$alsactl restore
```

I generally have it mapped in my ***~/.zshrc*** as

```
alias fixaudio="alsactl restore"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, that didn't work. You can find more details of my problem in [antergos forum](https://forum.antergos.com/topic/11552/headphones-recognised-but-produce-no-sound/5). The file /var/lib/alsa/asound.state has following lines at the start:
`control.1 {
  iface MIXER
  name 'Headphone Playback Volume'
  value.0 87
  value.1 87
  comment {
   access 'read write'
   type INTEGER
   count 2
   range '0 - 87'
   dbmin -6525
   dbmax 0
   dbvalue.0 0
   dbvalue.1 0
  }`